# Parameterize URL with parameters from list

Tags: python, locust

I have a simple GET request I want to parameterize with values from a list I also have in my script.

```
import json
import random
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser
import string
# import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import base64
from locust import HttpUser, between, task

server_name = "h t t p s://xxx.com:7072"

# Basic authentication:
username = xxx
password = "xxx"
auth_token = f"{username}:{password}"
# Encode the authentication token in base64:
auth_token_bytes = auth_token.encode("ascii")
auth_header = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(auth_token_bytes).decode("ascii")

headers = {'X-API-KEY': 'xxx', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

ts_ids = {
'14881',
'15016',
'15020'
}


 class TimeSeriesUser(FastHttpUser):
  host = server_name

   @task(1)
     def test_get_ts_1(self):
       self.timeseriesinfo(random.sample(ts_ids, 1))

    def timeseriesinfo(self, ts_ids_local):
        # Make the GET request with authentication:
        response = self.client.get(f'api/timeSeriesInfo?tsIds={ts_ids_local}', 
        headers=headers)
        # Check the response:
         if response.status_code == 200:
        print("SaveValues successful!")
        print("Response:", response.json())
        else:
        print("SaveValues failed.")
        print("Response:", response.text)
```

But running this test I get the error:

```
ERROR/locust.user.task: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7072api'
```

What is the problem here?

Is the URL a int?

I have changed the URL to be able to post this question.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Isn't the problem obvious from the error?  You need to add a slash to your URL, either at the end of `server_name` or at the beginning of `f"api/timeSeriesInfo..."`.  You're smashing them together at `httpx://xxx.com:7072api/timeSeriesInfo`.

Comment: Yes, it was the / missing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was the / missing, however, when running the test the output is not as expected. Looking at Locust web-gui I see that the URLs are constructed as this:

```
GET /api/timeSeriesInfo?tsIds=['101892']
```

I want them to be like this:

```
GET /api/timeSeriesInfo?tsIds=101892
```

What can I do with

```
response = self.client.get(f'api/timeSeriesInfo?tsIds={ts_ids_local}', 
    headers=headers)
```

to remove the [' and ']

?